# Python Requests package hits url twice

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I am trying to create a synonym list for words by hitting a synonyms api.  I am using Flask and the requests package.

I am calling this function only once after grabbing information from a webform via a flask route.

Code:

```
import requests
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, flash
import environment

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        keywords = request.form["key1"]
        synonyms = syn_look(keywords)
        return render_template("index.html", syns=synonyms)
    return render_template("index.html")


def syn_look(word):
    URL = "http://words.bighugelabs.com/api/2/%s/%s/json"
    request_url = URL %(environment.thesaurus_api_key, word)
    r = requests.get(request_url)
    print r.status_code

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = False
    app.run()
```

The status prints twice

output:

```
 * Restarting with reloader
 * Detected change in 'server.py', reloading
 * Restarting with reloader
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jan/2014 17:22:03] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
200
404
```

Comment: Can you please give the exact output of your program?

Comment: { * Restarting with reloader
 * Detected change in 'server.py', reloading
 * Restarting with reloader
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jan/2014 17:22:03] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
200}

404
}

Comment: Please post the entire code of your application, especially the part where you are calling `syn_look` method.

Comment: It is unlikely to be the cause of your question, but this cannot ever display to you the synonyms you're trying to generate. You never return the list from the website you're using so `render_template('index.html', syns=synonyms)` will be equivalent to `render_template('index.html', syns=None)`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain you're formatting `request_url` correctly?

You can see in the GET request, a 404 is printed on the last line. This is the [HTTP 404 Error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes), file not found. I'm betting this is why you see the 'reloading' messages in the console output.